# MacBook Pro 9,2, Ubuntu 12.10, Wifi works after suspend but not after reboot

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a MacBook Pro 9,2 (Mid-2012). I was able to successfully install and configure wifi using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Quantal). Great! However, when I reboot, the wireless card is recognized, but no wireless networks are detected.

That is, however, until I close the lid and the computer is suspended. When I reopen the lid, networks are detected normally.

Here is the output from `dmesg | greb b43`:

```
[   20.542046] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[   20.681680] Registered led device: b43-phy0::tx
[   20.681697] Registered led device: b43-phy0::rx
[   20.681714] Registered led device: b43-phy0::radio
[   22.563187] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  299.971510] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

Here is the output from `lspci | grep BCM`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
01:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
```

And b43 is included in my `/etc/modules`.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, there is no out-of-the-box support for the wireless card of my macbook pro 9,2. But it can be activated by installing the package bcmwl-kernel-source:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

That worked for me.
On the other hand, the sd card reader (integrated ethernet and card reader on broadcomm bcm57765 chipset) does not work and I haven't found a solution yet. If anybody did so, please let us know.